# header(Refresh makes page blank...but only on one network?

Tags: php

Given the following code (and only this code):

```
<?php 
if (headers_sent()) {
  die('cannot send location header (anymore)');
}
else {
  header("Refresh: 0; url=http://www.google.com"); //This does not work
  //header("Location: http://www.google.com"); //This does work
  die();
}
?>
```

Does anyone have any thoughts/suggestions why this will not work on a particular network?

The above codes directs to Google on 3 of the 4 networks I have tested (home, my work, a friend's home network).

However, when I load this page on my client's network, he only gets a blank page.

The commented code above is my workaround...but I would really love to know why Refresh would not work on this one particular network.

Comment: Since you output no actual content beyond headers, aren't the two equivalent? The second is a more standard technique than the first.

Comment: What are the servers running? Apache? IIS?

Comment: The server where the code is hosted is Apache.  I don't know my client's network.

Comment: Why do you use refresh: 0 instead of a simple Location?

Comment: Mat, I explained my issue in its simplest form.

Please refrain from redirecting the subject-matter.

If you don't have a theory or have a question that will lead to an answer for the issue listed above, don't bother posting.

Comment: I wonder if your client's server sends some headers, perhaps via an `auto_prepend_file`. Check with a traffic sniffer to see what exactly your client's server returns: Fiddler, Firebug, HttpFox, Wireshark will do

Comment: Actually it's probably not doing that, else you'd be seeing the `die` message. Barring any errors (check with `ini_set('display_errors', 1) ; error_reporting(E_ALL)`), my guess is the refresh header doesn't take on that combination of server/client. http://codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=73795 suggests `url` needs to be capitalized.

Comment: Regarding @MatTheCat's comment: that's a perfectly reasonable question. You may have a good reason for not using the Location header, but there are people out there who might not, and the question didn't make it clear which of those two groups you fell into. Now that it's settled that you have a good reason, I'm really just curious :) Not rhetorical: if there's no output in the body, what's the difference?

Comment: Or is there something inside the `die()` in the real code that wasn't included here?

Comment: @Matchu, the code is a snippit of Ion_auth:  a security extension for the framework CodeIgniter.  (http://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth)  In it, there are around 16 different calls to the URL helper's redirect method. (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html).  I figure there must be some reason they are using Refresh over location and, in fact, in their documentation they say that using Location can "sometimes cause problems on the Windows Server."  That's the main reason I used refresh in the example.  They're picking it...and I don't like changning framework

Comment: code unless there is a good reason for it.  However, you and Gumbo's answers, have helped justify my fix.  The varying output on my client's network as opposed to the others was just confusing.  It's possible there's some piece of hardware on his network (or ISP) stripping out that redirect...I dunno...just seemed weird.  anyway, thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Refresh* is not an [official HTTP header field](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html). Although [HTML’s `META` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#edef-META) with `http-equiv` attribute might implicate that anything that works there should also work with the real HTTP, *Refresh* was never an actual HTTP header field (and `http-equiv` does not mean HTTP-equivalent).

Just use the standard [*Location*](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously browser dependent - has your client tried this in multiple browsers? The Refresh header has been deprecated (for numerous reasons) by w3c in favor of Location; support for it is entirely up to the browser.

Comment: Since I used *MY* laptop with the same two browsers at three of the four locations listed above (including my client) and only experienced this issue at my client's office,  this is NOT "obviously browser dependent".  Try again.